# spring http outbound gateway customization

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

My requirement is to call siebel soap webservice, In the process handle request and response on a same method call, so that I can add token to the request header from the apache common pool and once get the response with token, grab the token from response and send it to pool. Here I have  mechanism to verify old token too, 
I need request token and response token on same class.

Future planning to add retry mechanism.

Currently I am using SI Http outbound gateway.

Any thoughts, appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need is named pre- and post-process. Not sure why you don't use Spring Integration WS support for calling that Siegel service, but even with the HTTP you can get a gain via `Interceptor` abstraction.

What I mean that you can inject `RestTemplate` into HTTP Outbound Gateway supplied with the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` implementation to provide a desired logic.

If you'd use WS Outbound Gateway, you could do that in the similar `ClientInterceptor` abstraction.

Of course, you can achieve that via `HeaderMapper` implementation, but that has different responsibility...

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to achieve this, 
Created a class to extends HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler than overrided handleRequestMessage()

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound